# MarkDown tables not rendering in Pelican

Tags: markdown, pelican

I'm using Python3 and Pelican to make static sites, but the MarkDown Tables feature is not working.

**Input:**

```
Test Columns | Header 2
------------ | --------
Test Value   | Test 2
```

**Output:**

Rows of data:

Test Columns | Header 2 ------------ | -------- Test Value | Test 2

Help?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OK, apparently Python Markdown just doesn't support MarkDown tables and it's a known issue. Using HTML table instead worked:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Test Columns</th><th>Header 2</th></tr>
<tr><td>Test Value</td><td>Test 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Makes the table render properly.

Comment: It does not seem necessary any more, it now works by default.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: apparently this extension is now enabled by default, no need for manual activation any more.

You can enable the [table extension for markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/tables/) by activating the "extra" extensions in your `pelicanconf.py`:

```
MARKDOWN = {
    'extension_configs': {
        'markdown.extensions.codehilite': {
            'css_class': 'highlight',
        },
        'markdown.extensions.extra': {},
        # optionally, more extensions,
        # e.g. markdown.extensions.meta
    },
    'output_format': 'html5',
}
```

Comment: It does not seem necessary any more, it now works by default.